# QGIS printing to file, shading?

Tags: qgis, printing

I am not even sure how to ask this question and I have Googled what I think is wrong with no success.

When I create a map with different shadings on it, it looks perfect until it is wrote to PDF.

I want the hatching/shading to display as it does on screen.

[image: What I see on screen]

what is printed

[image]

Comment: I know it is something to do with zoom and display but how do i change the settings.

Comment: Did you get the same Result's when exporting to a png ?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your pictures, are the hatchings the same but differently sized? in which case it is to do with DPI?

Comment: Yeah sorry about the images, i am trying to maintain the clients confidentiality. The second image is as a result of file>print>print to pdf. Gave up on exporting to pdf as it was having funny consequences.  Same result when i export as any image type.

Comment: for DPI do i increase or decrease? I have tried at 300DPI and 600DPI.

Comment: yes sorry the second image is done through the print composer. i have merely selected a small portion of the drawing for demonstration purposes and to maintain the privacy of the clients identity.

Comment: Try 72 or 96 DPI

Comment: ok so dropped it to 90 or 150. but the quality of the background mapping is dropped. can i print the background maps high res and the front layers low res.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Thanks for all the help. The best was to reduce it to screen quality. However i did not want to sacrifice the background mapping.

Perhaps my question was not clear enough but the answer i stumbled upon was inherently simple.

Previously (as shown above) i was using Simple Fill, if i change to line fill it give the results as follow:

[image]

So thanks again and i would not have come across it without your perseverance.

Comment: I know i used different colours here...sorry.